# How to create a dynamic URL for a dynamic HTML file?

Tags: node.js, express

It's easy to render a static website whenever a user requests a webpage on our website.

But how can we create a dynamic URL of dynamic HTML pages? Following is the code:

```
var JSONFile = require('../assets/blog.json');
```

then:

```
router.get('/blog/:post', function (req, res, next) {
        var postname = req.params['post'];
        var title2 = JSONFile.postname.title;
        var content2 = JSONFile.postname.content;
        res.render(postname + '.html', {
                title = title2,
                content = content2
        })
```

I'm trying to create a blog. I just want to create a common template file for all the blog posts. But how it's possible? We don't only want to change the content but as well as the URL of the blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

So likely what you're looking for is a template engine. Many are compatible with express but my suggestion is either `pug` or `handlebars` because of their superior handling of string escaping.

An example of setting up express to use pug.. in your app.js:

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
```

then when you res.render('post', {content: content}) , it will look in your /views folder for a file called 'post.pug', and you can use pug as a way of templating html and filling it in with your `locals` object (which in the above example, would contain `content`).

[Here's a full breakdown!](http://funkyjavascript.com/using-pug-templates-with-express/)